# Matrix method of solving non homogenous linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

> For a real number $\alpha$, if the system of linear equations
> $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \alpha & \alpha ^{2} \\ \alpha & 1 & \alpha \\ \alpha ^{2} & \alpha & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}$ $ = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$
> has infinitely many solutions, find $\alpha$.

Let

$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \alpha & \alpha ^{2} \\ \alpha & 1 & \alpha \\ \alpha ^{2} & \alpha & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

$X=\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}$

$D=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$

The equation can be written as $AX=D$

I learnt that this system(for $D \neq 0$. i.e. non homogenous system of equations):

> has a unique solution if $A$ is a non-singular matrix($|A| \neq 0$)
>
> has infinite number of solutions if $A$ is a singular matrix ($|A|=0$) and $adj(A)*D=0$.
>
> has no solution if $A$ is a singular matrix ($|A|=0$) and $adj(A)*D \neq 0$.

Solving for $|A|=0$, we get $\alpha = \pm 1$.

But here comes my doubt. In this case, $adj(A)=0$ (null matrix) for both  $\alpha = \pm 1$.
So $adj(A)*D=0$ for both those values. So according to what I learnt, for both $\alpha = \pm 1$ there should be infinite solutions to this system of equations.

But on expanding the matrix into a system of linear equations, it is easily observed that for $\alpha=1$ there are no solutions and for $\alpha=-1$ there are infinite solutions.

I feel that the condition $adj(A)*D$  equal to or not equal to 0 for infinite or no solution respectively is valid only if $adj(A) \neq 0$. Is this correct?

How can we deal with this case without having to expand it into a system of linear equations and verifying with values? (as that can get very tedious at times)

P.S: I have verified all my calculations with a calculator as well so there are no calculation mistakes.

Comment: Did you not make a mistake in calculating the adjoint?

Comment: I don't think so. I got $adj(A)=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} - \alpha^{2} + 1 & \alpha^{3} - \alpha & 0 \\\\ \alpha^{3} - \alpha & - \alpha^{4} + 1 & \alpha^{3} - \alpha \\\\ 0 & \alpha^{3} - \alpha & - \alpha^{2} + 1 \end{array} \right]

Comment: I verified this with calculator also. And this is a null matrix for both $\alpha = \pm 1$

Comment: My apologies, you're quite right. Well, then, something must be wrong with the statement that if $A$ is singular, and that product is zero, then there are infinitely many solutions. Do you have a citation for that? Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2653517/inconsistent-system-and-adjoint and see whether that helps.

Comment: Yes I also think that that statement is incorrect. I asked my teacher today and he said that you can't determine exactly if it has infinite solutions or not(the same information as that given in the link you gave).

Comment: This statement was given in one of my books(not no trustworthy as few mistakes are there in it), and I couldn't find the same in any other book. So mostly probably it is incorrect.

Comment: I think this question can be closed now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is incorrect